# Second hive query is failing due to FAILED: ParseException line 5:101 missing EOF in first hive query

Tags: hive, hql

I am working on exception handing in .hql file below is my script

```
use galaxy60_1000;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scd_member1 (scd_member_key string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/AutomationFiles/galaxy60_1000/scd_member

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scd_member3 (scd_member_key string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/AutomationFiles/galaxy60_1000/scd_member';
```

---

**Problem statement**

1. Here first hive query is failing due to

> FAILED: ParseException line 5:101 missing EOF

thats correct but second hive query is not working because its trying to execute below query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scd_member3 (scd_member_key string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
```

I am really confused why its not considering query that i wrote in my script

Comment: could you please check your question. I see no difference except the table names. The semicolon might be missing in the first query

Comment: Whats wrong in question ??

I explicitly made mistake in first query because as mentioned in title i am working on exception handling

Comment: Ok.. got you.. so you want to handle exceptions by introducing syntax errors?.. It depends on the parser.

Answer (score 0):

> I am really confused why its not considering query that i wrote in my
>   script

Your first `CREATE` statement missing the `'` at the end, and `;` to seperate the two commands.

Generally speaking, synthax analyzers cannot find all mistkes at one time, the first synthax mistake found will hide the rest. In the case of scripts, the execution may continue based on erronous parsed code !

To be sure, you can fix only the first mistake and see how it will be.

It should be like :

```
use galaxy60_1000;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scd_member1 (scd_member_key string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/AutomationFiles/galaxy60_1000/scd_member';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE scd_member3 (scd_member_key string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/AutomationFiles/galaxy60_1000/scd_member';
```